# MYSQL SELECT returns nothing on FK field with NULL values

Tags: mysql, database, null, tree, foreign-keys

I am trying to make some sort of tree with database using foreign keys. So, there is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
   id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   pid INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT TheTree FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES tree (id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

#insert sample data with 2 root nodes and 2 subnodes
insert into tree (id, pid, title) values 
     (null, null, 'test title 1'), 
     (null, null, 'test title 2'), 
     (null, 1,    'test title 1-1'), 
     (null, 2,    'test title 2-1');


select * from tree where pid = null
# it returns nothing.
```

Here goes [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34e4463/1) example.
I just didn't get it. Why i can't get my root nodes with NULL values? How can i deal it?

Comment: `pid = null` does nothing you need to use `pid is null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `is null`instead of `= null`:

```
select * from tree where pid is null
```

Comment: That's fine! But, what is i have to use NULL value as a variable? `$someVar = 'NULL' `; query('select * from tree where pid = $someVar')...`

Comment: You would need to add a `OR` to your `WHERE` clause: `SELECT * FROM tree WHERE pid IS NULL OR pid = @val;` or use the `COALESCE` function to convert it to a unused value: `SELECT * FROM tree WHERE COALESCE(pid, 'NULL') = @val;`